# How to add Shopify development app to development store

Tags: shopify

I've done the following:

- Created a partner account
- Created a dev store
- Created an app.

But I can't seem to find a way to add my app to my dev store. Can someone please explain how I can add it to my dev store without putting it in the app store?

Comment: Hey, can you tell me if you found a solution for this?

Comment: @Junaid Until your app is published in app store, you can install it in your dev shops by directly accessing this url in your browser  http://<dev-shop-name>.myshopify.com/admin/api/auth?api_key=<your-api-key>

Answer (score 1):

The app needs to be authorized with oAuth before it can become part of the development store. Details [here](http://docs.shopify.com/api/tutorials/oauth).