# how to successfully install App into Test Store?

Tags: php, shopify, shopify-activemerchant

I am facing the problem of installation Shopify App into Test Store. I have used the same code for the App which is given by `shopify_app-skeleton`. My `conf.php` code is:

```php
<?php
    define('SHOPIFY_APP_API_KEY', '5301a720e59f3d95bbb71284d1292d7f');
    define('SHOPIFY_APP_SHARED_SECRET', '30d6c4103712ca6dc3ffc37e76f739ec');
    define('REDIRECT_URL', 'http://localhost/shopify/app1/newPrj/getproducts.php ');
```

Still I have the problem to access App into the store and getting the same problem.

I get that error after click on **Install App** from the Store dashboard. Means after running this link: `http://localhost/shopify/app1/new_prj/install.php?shop=fashionstar-3.myshopify.com`
It redirects to store screen where a user clicks on **Install App**.
- [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aTzX.png)

When I click on the **Install App** it is not getting anything as an output. It shows install status on my App developer dashboard but does not redirect to `get_products.php` page.

Comment: Are you sure your `REDIRECT_URL` is correctly working? Also check - `https://engineering.shopify.com/17488288-developing-shopify-apps-part-1-the-setup` and `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576180/how-to-add-shopify-development-app-to-development-store`

Comment: @HymnZ Yes, redirect URL is working. I have checked using  http://localhost/shopify/app1/newPrj/oauth.php this URL as a redirect URL.
I think oauth_token is not store into session. 
Please suggest, how to get oauth_token?

Comment: You follow the procedure here. - https://help.shopify.com/api/guides/authentication/oauth

Comment: @HymnZ I have to follow the procedure of Shopify forum, I fail to get access token... If you are the developer then please send the code for how to get oauth_token?

I am using 
$oauth_token = shopify\access_token($_GET['shop'], SHOPIFY_APP_API_KEY, SHOPIFY_APP_SHARED_SECRET, $_GET['code']);  
for ouath_token

Comment: Are you developing a public app or private app?

Comment: @VidhiKhatri for developing & testing shopify apps, you need to have your own hosting ( shared is enough ) or vps. you cannot use `localhost` for this purpose. 

becuase your localhost ( your machine ) is not visible to shopify server, that's why you getting a blank screen after installing your app.

Comment: @HymnZ  I am developing public App.

Comment: @Sark Thanks for the information. But, If I want to run App with localhost then, Is there any other way to fetch data from Shopify store?

Answer (score 0):

Vidhi, you can use a tool called [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to create a tunnel between Shopify and your localhost. After this you can run the app from your localhost.

And you better use a PHP SDK for Shopify (there are many unofficial SDKs available), than performing direct HTTP requests.